# can we install maria db on ubuntu touch device?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, sql, mariadb

can we install maria db server on ubuntu tablet(ubuntu touch) ?
i'm trying to install ubuntu touch on a tablet, and i want it to act as portable sql server .
is that doable with ubuntu touch

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See [Turn Your Phone into a Portable Web Server](http://blog.kaiserapps.com/2013/11/turn-your-phone-into-portable-web-server.html)

Ubuntu Touch is still Ubuntu, Linux!

Use a Terminal app and do whatever you like.

(You might consider a Raspberry Pi with Wifi however. That's a lot cheaper and probably does whatever you need, and can be run from a power pack.)